# Bubble mouse event to iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, kendo-ui, jquery-events

We have some kind of dashboard with several kendo windows in iframe.

When user drags window outside of edges of the mother iframe and cancels drag (releases left button), the
window sticks and follows mouse pointer.

```
$('<div/>').appendTo ('#div_widget').kendoWindow ({
    actions: ["Refresh", "Maximize", "Minimize"],
    height : 300,
    width  : 600,
    title  : "drag me outside jsFiddle iframe - I'll stick to mouse",
    iframe : true,
    content: "http://kendoui.com",
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XYXyj/8/

It is very annoying since our users are bad in precise aiming.

It looks like I need a way to pass mouse release event to child iframe.

Could you suggest any workarounds? Any other ideas to prevent "sticky" behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

What about following : http://jsfiddle.net/vojtiik/8CjVM/2/

```
$("#wrap").mouseleave(function(){
    $('#div_widget').trigger('mouseup');
});
```

Add some wrapper and once user leaves the iframe fire mouseup event. Size of the iframe can be determined dynamically and propagated back to your wrapper.

NOTE: in your fiddle (and mine) chrome throws "Blocked a frame with origin.." - the iframe is never inserted, therefore I hard coded height/width values - you will have this dynamic, to see the fiddle working properly on your screen, change the hight/width.